# angular 2 unable to reference a variable within a function

Tags: javascript, angular

I have an event listener that uses firebase functions in it. in the case the file is being uploaded and upon completion I want it to run a function found in another file. The code in the other file works as it  works in the onInit().

code:

```js
fileButton.addEventListener('change', (e: any) => {
      //gets the path of the file they want to upload
      var filePath= (<HTMLInputElement>document.getElementById('filePathInp')).value;
        //get file:
        var file = e.target.files[0];
        //get ID of user
        var user = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('user'));
        // Create a storage reference
        if (filePath != ''){
          var ref = (user.id) + '/'+ filePath + '/' + file.name;
        } else {
          var ref = (user.id) + '/' + file.name;
        }
        var storageRef = firebase.storage().ref(ref);
        //Upload file
        var task = storageRef.put(file);
        
        //update progress bar
        task.on('state_changed',
               
          function progress(snapshot){
            //calculate the percentage
            var percentage = (task.snapshot.bytesTransferred / task.snapshot.totalBytes) * 100;
            //display the percentage completed
            uploader.value = String(percentage);
        },
          function(err){
            //throw error if error occurs
            throw(err);
            
        },
          function complete(){
            //upon completion console log
            console.log('COMPLETE!!');
((FileuploadComponent) => this.auth.sendFileStruct({msg: 'hello'}).subscribe(data => {}));
            
        });
        
        
    });
    };
```

The issue is with
     "((FileuploadComponent) => this.auth.sendFileStruct({msg: 'hello'}).subscribe(data => {}));"

It doesn't run auth.sendFileStruct

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`this` inside a function declared with the keyword `function` references the function, no longer the class. You can either use arrow function like that:

```
task.on('state_changed',
   snapshot => {/*progress function content*/},
   err => {/*error function content*/},
   ...
);
```

Or less elegantly bind `this` in a variable to keep the reference.

```
var that = this;
...
that.auth.sendFileStruct(...)
```

Answer (score 1):

You have defined a function that should be called immediately, so you have to do like this:

```
// add the parenthesis at the end 
 ((FileuploadComponent) => this.auth.sendFileStruct({msg: 'hello'}).subscribe(data => {}))();
```

Or get the function into a variable and call it by the current this object